# How to customize toolbar icons in Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I want to remove one of the buttons from the "run toolbar" because I keep pressing it accidently.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I see that there is an option to select/deselect the 'Run Toolbar' option. For this, click **View > Toolbars > Run Toolbar**

Check also the image for more clarification.
I have tried this from Spyder (Python 3.8)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To add a new entry to our toolbar, you need to create a Spyder plugin for it.

This [Github repo](https://github.com/spyder-ide/plugin-examples) contains some simple examples that use our API for things like that. They can be a bit outdated with respect to the most recent API version, but they should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for info. So I'll wait for further future :P

Comment: That's a bummer.  It would be really nice to have a textbox on the toolbar to include your argument list instead of having to dig into Run->configuration per file -> General Settings -> Command line options

Comment: @tzg, this is possible now in Spyder 5. Please see my new answer above.